# Can a type correct function be inapplicable? (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, type-inference

I have a function `foo = \f x -> let c = \y -> x in f c` which I have type inferenced to find :

`\forall a,b,r. ((b -> a) -> r) -> a -> r`.

GHCI confirms this type: `foo :: ((p1 -> p2) -> t) -> p2 -> t`

However, I am unable to find an applicable function that meets these parameters such that `foo` evaluates.

I have tried the following functions with no success:

```
bu :: Num a => ([Char] -> a) -> a
bu x = (x "hello") * 2 

ba :: (Fractional a1, Foldable t) => t a2 -> a1
ba x = (fromIntegral (length x) ) / 2
```

Another attempt was choosing the following functions:

```
bu :: Num a => ([Char] -> a) -> a -> a
bu x = (+ ((x "hello") * 2))

ba :: (Fractional a1, Foldable t) => t a2 -> a1
ba x = (fromIntegral (length x) ) / 2
```

Now I can call `(bu ba) 4`and get a correct result.

I understand why those don't work.
The issue seems to be that in the first arguement `(p1 -> p2) -> t)`, `t` would need to be a function that takes the argument `p2`. However, as soon as we do that the type of that function changes to something like `(a -> a)` and can no longer be correctly consumed by foo.

This exercise has lead me to the question; can a function with a correct type be inapplicable?
My intuition leads me to believe that this is false and that an applicable input exists for any function with a valid type. Is there a proof for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a simple proof that a function can be inapplicable (disregarding bottoms)

```hs
data Never = Never Never

justTryIt :: Never -> ()
justTryIt _ = ()
```

However your function IS applicable

```hs
main = print $ foo (\c -> c ()) 3
```

So what is the type of that lambda?

```hs
g :: (() -> a) -> a
g = \c -> c ()
```

Point is you don't need a function of

```hs
g :: (a -> b) -> c
```

Which is uninhabited (iGnOrInG bOtToMs). The type signature is just saying you can take a function where all 3 of those type (forall a b c.) *can* vary. IE this works equally as well

```hs
g :: (Int -> String) -> Bool
g f = null $ f 3

main = print $ foo g "so concrete"
```

Answer (score 5):

A function of type `p1 -> p2` is impossible to write; that basically says "given any possible type, I can give you any other possible type". Good luck with that!

The type `(p1 -> p2) -> t` is impossible for a similar reason. However, `(p1 -> p2) -> Bool` is quite possible:

```
f :: (p1 -> p2) -> Bool
f x = True
```

You can write similar functions for various choices of type `t`. (What you *can't* do is write a function that can somehow return *any possible `t`* out of nothing.)

More generally, can every implementable function be successfully called? That's an interesting question. I'm not sure what the answer is. I'd love to know!

**EDIT:** Thinking about it... the type signature of every *implementable* function can be interpreted as a theorum (and the implementation of the function is in some sense a "proof" of that theorum). A function that takes another function as input is like "this theorum is true if this other theorum is true". So if you can come up with a proof that "X is true if Y is true", where Y is definitely false... then you have your implementable function that can never be called.

All of this cheerfully ignores that real Haskell has several ways to break the type system and get around these nice results. For example, the function `error "banana"` has type `a` (i.e., *any possible type*). So in this "cheating" sense, all Haskell functions are callable.

Comment: ‘can every implementable function be successfully called?’ If I understand you correctly, not necessarily: e.g. [`absurd`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Void.html#v:absurd), or @Fresheyeball’s answer (which implements the same function)